# Define Java map of key String and value can be any type including a map

Tags: java, generics, maps, wildcard

Is it possible to define a map object in Java where the key is a string and the value can be either a string, number, date, or another map?

Following is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
Map<String,? super String> myMap1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
myMap1.put("streetAddress", "123 street name");
myMap2.put("city", "New York");

Map<String,? super String> myMap2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
myMap2.put("name", "John Smith");
myMap2.put("age", 35);
myMap2.put("salary", 67000);
myMap2.put("dob", parseDate("1980-03-20"));
myMap2.put("address", myMap1);
```

The above will most likely result in a compile error, and I need help to be able to initialize such map.

My objective is to create a map object that can map a string key to a date, string, number, or another map. How is that possible?

Comment: Use `Map<String, Object>`

Comment: … and use a full constructor for the maps, like `new HashMap<String, String>()` (add braces).

Comment: Looks like you want `Address` and `Person` classes.

Comment: @SaifAhmad Thanks... Is there a way to find out what is the type of value of a given key? Or the developer must know what is the type and use casting to covert to the correct type?

Comment: Developer must know otherwise there will be multiple switch cases to detect the type.

Comment: @tarekahf `"Is there a way to find out what is the type of value of a given key?"` - seems like you've introduced an [XY-problem](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiGwJ_o5476AhWHgSoKHVw2BJUQFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F66377%2Fwhat-is-the-xy-problem&usg=AOvVaw1RW8UpIl7QYxoW-PU7zAk9).

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
    Map<String, String> myMap1 = new HashMap();
    myMap1.put("streetAddress", "123 street name");
    myMap1.put("city", "New York");

    Map<String, Object> myMap2 = new HashMap();
    myMap2.put("name", "John Smith");
    myMap2.put("age", 35);
    myMap2.put("salary", 67000);
    myMap2.put("dob", LocalDate.parse("1980-03-20"));
    myMap2.put("address", myMap1);

    System.out.println(myMap2.toString());//{address={streetAddress=123 street name, city=New York}, dob=1980-03-20, name=John Smith, salary=67000, age=35}
```

Map<String, Object> - key - String, value - any object

Comment: Wow! Did you try the code above and it worked? Can you please move the line to add the `city` field to be part of the `address` map? Will that work?

Comment: @tarekahf I edited my answer as per your request.

Comment: thanks a lot, I will try the code snippet you provided with vscode and will update back.